# SIGSEGV when trying to change string in structure C/C++

Tags: c++, c, sockets, struct

I have a structure like this

```
    typedef struct {
    string aPath;
    string dPath;
    string tmpPath;
    int cSet;
    int socket;
    } threadParams;
```

And some variables like this

```
string dirPath = "./Maildir/";
string authPath;
string tmpPath = "~/tmpPath/";
```

Im trying to initialize structure and add some data like this

```
            threadParams *tP = (threadParams*)malloc(sizeof(threadParams));
            tP->aPath = authPath;
            tP->cSet = cParam;
            tP->dPath = dirPath;
            tP->socket = commSocket;
            tP->tmpPath = tmpPath;
```

When I run program with this code there is SIGSEGV signal while trying to execute this: tP->aPath = authPath; when i delete these string members of structure and keep just int variable its okay, everything works properly.

Can anyone tell me why is this happening and how to fix it? Thank you

Comment: This is C++ not C. Use `new` and `delete` not `malloc` and `free`.

Comment: `This is C++ not C.` @Captain Obvlious you do not know it. It can be `typedef char * string;` or `#define string char *`

Comment: @PeterJ_01 Actually even with the small code snippet it's clear there's a high probability the OP is either trying to transition from C to C++, learning both at the same time, or mixing the two together. it's a common mistake and not really difficult to identify as the most likely thing happening here.

Comment: @PeterJ_01 _"when i delete these string members of structure and keep just int variable its okay"_ gives it away.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious  oh,come on man! Next thing is gonna be: "you go to  jail if you use malloc/free instead of new/delete" . SO could be a better place without this sort of remarks.

Comment: @MichaelIV Well you are certainly free to use `malloc` and `free` to your hearts content but if you're using them in C++ for anything other than POD types you're not going to get very far.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious  fair enough. That's not clear from your original remark.

Comment: @MichaelIV What's not clear about a basic well known rule in C++? What _good_ book on C++ doesn't include this when it covers dynamic storage duration? you're being melodramatic for nothing.

Comment: @CaptainObvlious your original statement is too explicit or even unequivocal. Some people are new to C++ and when one says something like that, someone else might think that's forbidden by a standard.I personally use malloc/free as much as possible (for POD types), and if I were a C++ noob I would get confused on this sort of statement.Nothing personal, man.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

when you allocate the structure, you are only allocating the size of the threadparams struct.  The underlying strings are not being properly constructed.  Internally, they are pointers to unallocated memory.

As stated previously, when creating a dynamic object, use 'new'  this will allocate and properly construct the object and all object elements it contains.

Comment: Thank you both for help.